# How the akka-persistence-cassandra and Tags play together?

Tags: cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

until now I only used akka-persistence-cassandra with journal plugin and didn't paid too much attention to Tags.

Lately I experimented little bit to understand how it works, but there are some points that are really confusing me, so I like to ask those here...

Now, I understand that Tags exists so that Cassandra can creates over tags and timebuckets partitions to be able to prevent hotspots in Cassandra.

When I configure the cassandra-journal plugin and Event Tags, I see the following Tables in Cassandra Key Space, messages, metadata, tag_scanning, tag_views, tag_write_progress...

Now if no Tags are configured, journal plugins writes only to messages table but if event tags are also configured, it persist both to messages and tag_scanning, tag_views, tag_write_progress tables...

- So first question, what is the advantage or reason of writing both messages and tag_scanning, tag_views, tag_write_progress, does this not mean more load for Cassandra?
- Second questions, am I doing something wrong do I have to turn off something in Journal Plugin somehow, so it will not persist to messages...

What am I missing here?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 3):

Tags are not specific to the Cassandra journal plugin, but a generic concept for Akka Persistence/Akka Persistence Query allowing an event sourced application to tag a subset of the events and separately consume those events as a stream.

Tagging is commonly used to split/shard updating a projection up into several workers, see for example the CQRS Akka samples here: https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.6/akka-sample-cqrs-scala https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.6/akka-sample-cqrs-java

The events are always stored in the messages table, even if they are tagged, so tagging rather leads to some additional writes.

The `tag_write_progress` and `tag_scanning` are implementation details related to consistency and ordering of the tagged events.

If you are not using tags in your application you can disable `events-by-tag` support in the plugin completely since there is some overhead attached to maintaining the related tables.

Comment: First of all thx for your answer, but I still don't understand the benefit of Tags. I always thought they exist to increase the scaling factor for the shards but If I write and serialise twice it can't be that beneficial. So if I understand you correctly, if tags are used, during the actor recovery those will be used?

Comment: No, they are not used for recovery. Tags are opt in, so if you think the storage overhead is problematic for your use case, you can avoid that by not using tags.

Comment: I'm a little confused by Akka Projection and Akka Persistence Query. Could you kindly please explain it. Why should I consider using Akka Projection? I want to implement a CQRS app. some actors in cluster sharding persist events to Cassandra, and the read side get events by tag and publish to Kafka to be used in another microservice. Can I do it only with Persistence Query? is Akka Projection only a wrapper around Persistence Query? Any help would be greatly appreciated